# Non-Web Database for Android Apps

Tags: android, database, android-intent, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm VERY new to Mobile app development; starting from Android. I have a few basic questions:

1. The information of the users of the apps I plan on creating will be updated regularly (kinda like social networking status updates with photo sharing and possibly videos). Must I create a web platform parallel for this service with some dedicated web server in other to create a database for information to be stored by users of the app i create?
2. If there is an option (without web platform parallel) that for this, how does the app retrieve this info casually? Just through external intents?
3. Does Google have a server provision (paid or free) for this kind of solution? How much data storage/server space are Android developers given to access Google Cloud services normally?
4. Can "Google Cloud Endpoints" be a solution to this (without a web platform parallel), seeing that it also accommodates iOS? Found the GCE on the link below:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/

*/Any other options? (I'm thinking of the least cumbersome options of achieving this please)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you will be best served going with [App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/?csw=1) for now. App Engine is Google's Platform as a Service (PaaS), which allows you to build web applications using a variety of languages (Java, Python, Go and PHP).

Having said that, [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) will be your API to interact with your mobile clients. It will be hosted or running in the same App Engine application that can contain the rest of your functionality. Cloud Endpoints provides tools for generating Android / iOS clients, so you will be served well there.

When your mobile application makes a request to Cloud Endpoints, the Endpoints implementation will then invoke your business logic in the application and this can involve saving / persisting the kind of user information/social media data that you want to store.

For storage, Google Cloud Platform provides you with 3 options that you can utilize : [Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/), [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage/) (for Blobs/Files) and [Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/) which is a NoSQL like implementation. A combination of Cloud Datastore and Cloud Storage would go well for the kind of information that you want to save.

Now for specific answers to your queries:

1. Yes, you have to build an application which will be your web application. This application will be hosted on Google App Engine.
2. I believe this point does not apply. I suggest you invoke your own web application that is hosted on App Engine.
3. App Engine has a generous free quota which will suffice you well. Once you cross that limit, things are pay per usage. You can check out the pricing.
4. Google Cloud Endpoints is a good solution. It will work inside of your App Engine application (web application) and will provide the API (Interaction layer) between your Server side application and your mobile clients. Yes, it can generate the iOS and Android client code for you to speed up integration on the mobile side.

Comment: Wow.. Thanks alot @Romin. I totally get it now!